# AES128/CBC/PKCS7padding in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, encryption, aes, pkcs#7

I am attempting to decrypt the blob data for stories sent from Snapchat. Here is how gibsonsec describes the method to decrypting the image:

- Padded using PKCS#7.
- Encrypted using AES/CBC with a unique IV and key per piece of the story.

So is there some way to accomplish this, `AES128/CBC/PKCS7padding` within Objective-C? Indeed I do have both the `data` value (in NSData form), `key` value (encrypted in base63 form of NSString), and `iv` value (again, encrypted in base63 form of NSString)

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Harry have you got your answer?

Answer (score 3):

Found the following; https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor - Solved.

Comment: There is also https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor, but I don't know if it helps you.

Comment: RNCryptor [does not compatible](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor#can-i-use-rncryptor-to-read-and-write-my-non-rncryptor-data-format) with ordinary AES data.